# How to send an asset from node address to any other address in multichain?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

How to send asset from node address to any other address in multichain ?
I want to know is there any direct API call to do that  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cjcoders yes there is a direct api method to do that and that is sendassetfrom.
It's clearly mentioned in their [Docs](https://www.multichain.com/developers/json-rpc-api/).